# Shell Script to connect from one postgres database to another database using dblink

Tags: sql, postgresql, shell

ERROR:  function dblink_connect_u(text, text) does not exist
LINE 3: from dblink_connect_u(cast(varchar 'dbname=test_db...
             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Dear all,

I'm having error when execute my shell script to connect from one database to another database in different server using dblink. Above is showing the error i hit. By the way, i have checked my share directory in linux server, i have the function:
/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/dblink.sql

However, how come i still hitting the error above?

Below is my shell script code:

```
echo "Start insert records..."
psql cr032 <<THE_END
select t1.*
into test_table
from dblink_connect_u(cast(varchar 'dbname=TEST_DB port=5432 host=10.0.0.10 user=test password=123456' as text),
            cast(varchar 'select applicationid, appname, appversion, apppath, appdatetime, description, systemtype from test_table' as text))
       as t1(applicationid varchar(36), appname varchar(100), appversion varchar(20), apppath varchar(200), appdatetime timestamp, description text, systemtype smallint);
THE_END
echo "End insert records!"
```

Please kindly help and your assistance are highly appreciated!

Comment: It seems like you left out some code. What does the line calling db_connect_u actually look like?

Comment: Ah never mind it looks like you had a formatting issue that was hiding your code. I fixed it. Pending approval

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause of the error, this is because I didn't load dblink.sql into my postgres database after installed. 
Below is the command to load dblink.sql into postgres, execute the command under postgres/bin folder :

psql -d "database_name" < "dblink_location"/dblink.sql

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you omit the cast varchar...as text?
Also thinking along the lines of this below. You use dblink_connect_u to establish the connection, then dblink to execute the query.

```
   Select dblink_connect_u( 'connection1',
     'dbname=TEST_DB port=5432 host=10.0.0.10 
        user=test password=123456')

  select t1.*
   into test_table
   from dblink('connection1',
    'select applicationid, appname, appversion, apppath, 
     appdatetime, description, systemtype from test_table' )
   as t1(applicationid varchar(36), appname varchar(100), 
    appversion varchar(20), apppath varchar(200), 
      appdatetime  timestamp, description text, systemtype smallint);
```

Comment: Hi Neil Neyman, thanks for your replied and provided the suggestion solution. I have changed my code as you suggested, however, i'm still get the same error after test.

Comment: Hi Neil Neyman, i found the root cause of the error, this is because i didn't load dblink.sql into my postgres database after install. Below is the command to load dblink.sql into postgres, execute the command under postgres/bin folder : psql -d "database_name" < "dblink_location"/dblink.sql

Comment: Glad you solved It. You should add the solution as an answer to your own question because it might help someone else.